# How can I mix different columns in only one column using r code?

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, reshape

I'm work in some statistical analysis for a school project.
I have a data frame with too many data about the air temperature of a buoy in somewhere near Brownsville. I have something like this:

```
  Year91   Year92  and so forth... i have about 40 years
 a 25.3    e 12.3
 b 15.3    f 56.3
 c 25.8    g 14.5
 d 15.2    h 28.0
```

I read some articles, and writers say that i can use the cbind or rbind functions, but they doesn't work as the way i need.

I need mix the column because they have the same type of data, and I need a boxplot of every ten years. I want to do this:

```
  Year91to01
 a   25.3
 b   15.3
 c   25.8
 d   15.2
 e   12.3
 f   56.3
 g   14.5
 h   28.0
```

I hope you can understand my question. Thanks!

Comment: Are these 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' part of the column?  We can do `unlist(data)`

Comment: no, they are not part of the column. I just wanted to illustrate how the data is planned to mingle.

Comment: Okay, thanks please check the solution below.  It should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just do `unlist(data)` and create a `data.frame` based on that

```
res <- data.frame(Year91to01 = unlist(data, 
            use.names=FALSE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a tidy approach, use gather:

```
library(tidyr)
data <- data.frame(Year91 = c(25.3,15.3,25.8,15.2), Year92 = 
c(12.3,56.3,14.5,28.0))

clean <- gather(data)

clean

     key value
1 Year91  25.3
2 Year91  15.3
3 Year91  25.8
4 Year91  15.2
5 Year92  12.3
6 Year92  56.3
7 Year92  14.5
8 Year92  28.0
```